# Azure Function Startup issue

Tags: function, azure, .net-core

When deploying an Azure Function project, a null reference exception is thrown when inspecting the deployed functions in the Azure portal.  I can see all three of the functions I deployed, but they all fail to start.  I can run and debug this project just fine on my local computer.

This particular project has three different functions in it.  All three have their own Startup class to handle bootstrapping the function.  I thought that might be an issue (having three startup classes) so I tried consolidating to a single shared startup class, but that doesn't work either.  It doesn't throw the error, but I don't believe they executed either - it's been awhile since I tried that approach.

As I described, there are three functions in a single assembly that's being deployed.  Being relatively new to Azure Functions, what would be best practice here?  Is it recommended to have multiple functions in a single assembly?  Examples I see online show only single functions, I don't think I've seen an example with more than one function per project.  The contents of `extensions.json` are as follows:

```
{
  "extensions":[
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"My.Functions.ExtractAnalytics.Startup, My.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"},
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"My.Functions.ExtractMetrics.Startup, My.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"},
    { "name": "Startup", "typeName":"My.Functions.TrimMetricData.Startup, My.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
  ]
}
```

I thought maybe the `name` being the same for all three might be a problem, but the types are correct.  When I open the Azure portal and go to inspect the functions, I get a pink popup that shows the following:

```
Error:

The function runtime is unable to start. My.Functions: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Session Id: 17a68b8fba31433a974b5958f764aeb8

Timestamp: 2019-07-31T17:35:19.743Z
```

None of my logging works, as the runtime seems to fail immediately.

Comment: What version of the Functions SDK are you using? There was a bug fix recently released in version 1.0.28 to fix extensions.json files not being correctly built when publishing to Azure. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3386#issuecomment-419565714

Comment: looking in function app settings, I have the following : `Runtime version: 2.0.12590.0 (~2)`  that's quite a ways off from the version you mention here...?

Comment: The runtime version is what the service is running in the background. What you need to check is the version of the Nuget package that is included in your code. Important here is that it helps define how the code is built and published to Azure. The easiest place to find this will likely be your IDE.

Comment: ahh - I am using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.29)` - this appears to be the most up to date at this time.

Comment: So next step is to try the recommendations from the product team in the Github thread for those still having trouble. 1) Removing any custom targets files
2) Removing any direct reference to the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator package. The direct reference in particular seems to be problematic.

Comment: first, thanks for your continual responses here - I'm hoping to get to the bottom of this issue.

1 - removing any custom targets files - I'm assuming you mean build targets here, that would be referenced in the project?  there are no targets specified here.  please correct me if I'm not understanding you here.
2 - there is no direct reference to this package, but there is a dependency reference that I see from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` that pulls in `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator (1.1.2)`.

Comment: The issue is with the build steps, targets refers to custom build steps. the Extensions.MetadataGenerator reference as a dependency is fine. One of the workarounds with previous versions was to install it separately which is now causing issues since the bugfix.

Comment: Could you send me an email at azcommunity (at) microsoft.com with your subscription id and a link to this thread? I'll enable your subscription for a support request. It sounds like this would benefit from some more hands-on troubleshooting than Stack allows.

Comment: No problem. If you could come back and post the answer once you get it figured out I would appreciate it.